# Initializing Gem-Specific variables information in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jenkins

I am working right now on a Rails 4.0 application (using Ruby 2.0.0).

I would like to interact with Jenkins using [jenkins_api_client](https://github.com/arangamani/jenkins_api_client) gem, **from multiple pages of my Rails application**.

This gem generally using a    `@client` parameter, which is initialized to contain the credentials and other information of the Jenkins server.
This parameter in initialized using something like this:

```
@client = JenkinsApi::Client.new(:server_ip => '0.0.0.0',
     :username => 'somename', :password => 'secret password')
```

Once initialized, I would like to access this parameter and run multiple sub-routines on it.
This initialization takes time, and I really want to avoid doing this process every time one of the clients would like to use this gem functionality, such as:

```
# Get a filtered list of jobs from the server
jobs_to_filter = "^test_job.*"
jobs = @client.job.list(jobs_to_filter)
```

So, I hope to do this only once- when the rails server starts.

I would like to use this parameter from multiple pages of my app, possibly with threaded solution further down the road (not critical at the moment).

Can anyone recommend how to achieve this?
I'd appreciate an answer which is consistent with Rails convention.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it looks like you could initialize your singleton jenkins client from config/initilizers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.
Can you suggest how is this achieved?
Is this the rails convention of setting these parameters? (For example, I know that when other rails gems are imported specific files are created, and I haven't seen any of these files in config/initializers)

Comment: I have written some code example as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as example you could create something like that:

```
module JenkinsApi
  class Client
    class << self
      attr_reader :instance, :config

      def configure(&block)
        @config = OpenStruct.new
        block.call @config
      end

      def instance
        @instance ||= JenkinsApi::Client.new @config
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which allow you write in initializer:

```
JenkinsApi::Client.configure do |config|
  config.server_ip = '0.0.0.0'
  config.username = 'somename'
  config.password = 'secret password'
end
```

and then use it like: `JenkinsApi::Client.instance.job.list(...`

Comment: Thanks! 
Can you specify where each part of the code goes? (specifically the first part).
Also, should I use anywhere in my application "request" or "require" for the original gem?
Finally, would that have any constrains as a threaded application?

Comment: first part you can put to `lib/..` also you could require it in initializer part. What about threads I don't know why this could give some constraints

Comment: Got it. Thanks!
I shall implement this and comment in case of any errors.